# Open Keychain Access safety notes on iPhone?

Tags: keychain

Is it possible to open Keychain Access safety notes on iPhone?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, Secure Notes are not available on iOS.

If you wish to use password-protected notes cross-platform, you can use Notes.app.